# Task about graph theory and Euler path.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

Happy new year to all!

Could you explain me with this task from my Discrete Mathematics examination?

Suppose  is a simple undirected graph with  vertices, each having degree 5.

a) For which values of  does this make sense?

b) For which values of  does the graph have a Euler path?

c) What is the smallest value of  for which the graph might be planar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you have recently posted several questions like this one, all from your Discrete Math Exam, I should mention that it is expected that you show your work on the question first. In other words, what have you tried?

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein I'm new in Math.Stackexchange, sorry, I will mention earlier that I tried to do before, instead of just publishing my tasks, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) The maximum degree of a simple undirected graph with $n$ vertices is $n-1$, so we must have $n-1 \geq 5 \implies n \geq 6.$  One can also check that $K_6$ satisfies the assumptions, so $n \geq 6$ is a tight necessary condition.

**Note:** My original post stated that $n \geq 6$ is sufficient.  As Shahab pointed out in the comments, this is false since $n$ cannot be odd.  I believe $n \geq 6$ and $n$ even is necessary and sufficient, but you may want to check this.

---

b) An Euler path requires all but possibly two vertices to have even degree.  Since $n \geq 6$ vertices have odd degree, it cannot have an Euler path.

---

c) Since the number of edges $e = \frac{5n}{2}$ and for a simple undirected planar graph $e \leq 3n - 6,$ we have $n \geq 12.$  This is a necessary condition, but I bet you can find an example with $n=12,$ showing it is also sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Regarding (a) if $n$ is odd then the graph will have an odd number of vertices of odd degree, which is absurd.

Comment: @Shahab Right.  I ended up implicitly mentioning this in (c), but my claim $n \geq 6$ is _sufficient_ is certainly stating too much when I just mean the inequality is tight.  I'll add something to (a) to reflect this.